# Create a Python Dictonary by taking joins of two dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary, like so:

```
{0: 'Initialised', 1: 'Processed', 3:'Finished'}
```

I have a second Dictionary, like so:

```
{0: 81, 1: 100, 3: 906}
```

What I want is to get:

```
{'Initialised':81, 'Processed':100, 'Finished': 906}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share your effort ? And the second object `{0: 81, 1: 100, 3: 906}` is not a list its again a dictionary object.

Comment: That was a typo, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do something like this

```
In [31]: t1 = {0: 'Initialised', 1: 'Processed', 3:'Finished'}
In [33]: t2 = {0: 81, 1: 100, 3: 906}

In [34]: {t1[key]: t2[key] for key in t1}
Out[34]: {'Finished': 906, 'Initialised': 81, 'Processed': 100}
```

Without Dictionary Comprehension:

```
t3 = {}
for key in t1:
    t3[t1[key]] = t2[key]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Keep getting "global name 't2' is not defined" even tough it is as shown.

Comment: This may happen when you are using `t2` in a function and defining it in another, if you are using this logic in a function then define these `dictionary` in that function only or pass these as arguments

Comment: I am trying this on shell

Comment: I have figured out the problem. I am working on Django 1.4.10 which only seems to support Python till 2.5 which did not have Dictionary comprehension. Could you a non-DC way of doing this?

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for the patience and help!

Comment: Hey, how can I account for missing keys in t2? Putting the line inside if(t2[key]) doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Handles absence of keys in the second dict.

```
{v: d2.get(k, None) for k, v in d1.items()}
# {'Finished': 906, 'Initialised': 81, 'Processed': 100}
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it very simple ?

Example using dictionary comprehension (which is available from Python 2.7 onwards) -

```
>>> d1 = {0: 'Initialised', 1: 'Processed', 3:'Finished'}
>>> d2 = {0: 81, 1: 100, 3: 906}
>>>
>>> d = {d1[k]:d2[k] for k in d1.keys()}
>>> d
{'Finished': 906, 'Processed': 100, 'Initialised': 81}
```